# Append line break to every cat in pipe

Tags: shell, cat

I have the following pipeline:

```
find /my/place -name 'test_*_blub' | xargs cat
```

While this works fine, I also want to have all file content terminated by a line break (`\n`).

Could not yet figure out how to append the newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print a linebreak `\n` after each file content - use one of the following approaches:

1) running shell commands

```
find /my/place -name 'test_*_blub' | xargs -I % sh -c 'cat %; echo "";'
```

---

`sh -c 'cat %; echo "";'` - multiple commands executed one-by-one

---

2) with `-exec` action:

```
find /my/place -name 'test_*_blub' -exec cat {} \; -exec echo "" \;
```

---

3) with `-printf` action:

```
find /my/place -name 'test_*_blub' -exec cat {} \; -printf "\n"
```

Comment: Nice but would like to avoid a subshell.

Comment: @abergmeier, choose one of 3 approaches

Comment: Have used 3 actually because it needs least amount of escaping passing through other software and is straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an easy way:

```
find /my/place -name 'test_*_blub' | xargs cat | xargs -I '{}' echo '{}'
```

Comment: There has to be an easier way, though.